# How to open on click popup window in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to open a popup window in my shiny app so that I can plot my graphs in the popup window. All the Action Button should open a popup on click.

ui.r

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(



  fluidRow(align="center",

           column(8, align="center", offset = 2,

                  textInput("prod_code", label=h3("ANALYTICS"), value = ""),

                  tags$style(type="text/css", "#string { height: 50; width: 100%; text-align:center; font-size: 30;}"),
                  tags$style(type="text/css", "#plot1_dl { width:100; vertical-align:50%}"),



                  actionButton("Twitter_Sentiment_analysis","Twitter Sentiment analysis"),
                  actionButton("Twitter_wordcloud","Twitter WordCloud"),
                  actionButton("Twitter_Heatmap","Twitter Heatmap"),
                  actionButton("Ecommerce_Sentiment","Ecommerce Sentiment"),
                  actionButton("Ecommerce_Reviews","Ecommerce Reviews"),




                  textOutput("userenteredquery")



           )

  )

)

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `conditionalPanel`, where you set the condition to the number of clicks on your action button. Eg

```
conditionalPanel(
  condition = "input.Twitter_Sentiment_analysis % 2 == 1",
  absolutePanel(
    left = 10,
    top = 10,
    width = 800,
    plotOutput("Twitter_Sentiment_analysis_plot")
  )
)
```

An alternative would be to use `shinyBS::bsModal` which gives you a nice UI but requires another package.

Comment: are you sure that opens a popup window?